# When would the CancellationException happen?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I've been reading about handling exceptions with coroutines but there are a few things unclear for me yet.

1. When does a CancellationException occur? Do I have to assign the coroutine to a job and then, call job.cancel() in order for it to happen?
2. Looking at my code, will it ever catched? Or is it the first catch block useless?

```
    fun invoke(params: Params, onResult: (UseCaseResponse<Type>)?) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            try {
                val result = run(params)
                onResult?.onSuccess(result)
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: $result")
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: $e")
                onResult?.onError(apiErrorHandler.traceErrorException(e))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: $e cause: ${e.cause}")
                onResult?.onError(apiErrorHandler.traceErrorException(e))
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may sound as a stupid answer, but `CancellationException` occur when someone is throwing it.

Basically, yes, this exception should be thrown when the coroutine (or its parent coroutine) is canceled (yes, via `job.cancel()`). But it is the responsibility of the engineer, who writes suspend function to check, whether it was canceled and act respectfully (throwing `CancellationException`, for instance, as all suspending functions in `kotlinx.coroutines` do). So whether or not your code catches `CancellationException` depends on what happens inside `run(params)`.

See [Cancellation is cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative) and [Making computation code cancellable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable) for more information and code examples.

Comment: OK,so inside run I call my repository:  `override suspend fun run(params: Params): BuffDomainModel {  return repository.getBuff(params.id)   }`  which will make a rest api call using retrofit  `class BuffRepository {  suspend fun getBuff(buffId: Long) =
        BuffApi.retrofitService.getBuff(buffId).result.toDomainModel()  }`  `interface BuffApiService { @GET("buffs/{buffId}")
    suspend fun getBuff(@Path("buffId") buffId: Long) : BuffResponse } ` so to answer my own question, no, it won't be catched because I am not throwing it. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, it seems [Retrofit doesn't throw it](https://github.com/square/retrofit/search?q=CancellationException&type=code).

Comment: There is also a key primitive, `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, which completes with a `CancellationException` when you cancel the coroutine. So in fact you rarely have to check the `isActive` flag explicitly, but you do have to take care not to use `suspendCoroutine` instead, which is non-cancellable.